# Oracle date calculation issue

Tags: oracle, datetime

there is a requirement like below:

> string format is : dd hh:mm:ss, this means (days hours:minutes:seconds, day is optional)
>   now the string will add to value "1/1/4000", so if the incoming value is "00:15:00" the resulting value would be 1/1/4000 00:15:00 (add 15 minutes to 1/1/4000).  If the incoming value is 2 00:15:00 then the resulting value would be 1/3/4000 00:15:00 (add 2 days and 15 minutes to 1/1/4000) . If the incoming value is 32 00:15:00 then the resulting value would be 2/1/4000 00:15:00.
>
> so is there any simple method to implement this requirement above?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your input string to [INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00207) datatype using [TO_DSINTERVAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions204.htm#SQLRF06133) and then add it to your default date. The result will be a date.

```
date'4000-01-01' + TO_DSINTERVAL('2 23:23:12');
```

But this requires your input string to be in DD HH:MI:SS format. Since in your input, day is optional, you should append 0 days to the string, in case it isn't present.